# iPhone App Review and SHA1

Tags: ios, encryption, sha1, appstore-approval

My iPhone app uses SHA1 for password security over an instant messaging protocol.

Will I be required to declare my app as "containing encryption" when I submit it to Apple's review process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you say yes to that question, it will then ask you if you use it for anything other than authentication. In your case, you can answer no and proceed to submit your app as normal.

Answer (score 5):

A cryptographic hash function is not encryption. If Apple's wording is actually "encryption", you should definitely answer no.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you should declare the use of encryption functions.

The purpose of declaring it is that applications using encryption cannot be exported from some specific countries, or imported in some countries. I don't see any other reasons why Apple would ask you to declare when an application uses encryption.

Comment: Cryptography was once considered to be a military technology. But, these times are long over. Export restrictions have changed accordingly. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography.

Comment: Many regimes restrict the import of cryptographic software. Authoritarian repression is alive and well.